# Catch exception while streaming mp3

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I need to stream mp3 file in my app, and I face with a problem if a mp3 file that is located on the server is missing. So my code works great except when there is no mp3 on that location. Whenever that happens my app crashes. Can someone help me catch this error, and disable the app from crashing when there is no mp3 audio on that location.

Here is my code:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(data.get(position)
                                .getSONG_MP3());
                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                bufferingDialog.setMessage(activity
                                        .getString(R.string.buffering));
                                bufferingDialog.show();
                                super.onPreExecute();
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                                try {
                                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.v("--", "4");

                                    bufferingDialog.dismiss();
                                    ((AlbumDetails) activity)
                                            .changePicToPlay(position);
                                    playSong.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_nr);
                                    Toast.makeText(activity,
                                            "Song not existing",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                                if (bufferingDialog.isShowing())
                                    bufferingDialog.dismiss();
                                super.onPostExecute(result);
                            }
                        }.execute();
```

This is the logCat output:

```
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4050)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:709)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12677)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12677)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12677)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12677)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12677)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1690)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:801)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5592)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:35)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at com.outsourcefarm.musicagratis.activities.AlbumDetails.changePicToPlay(AlbumDetails.java:228)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at com.outsoucefarm.musicagratis.functions.AlbumDetailsAdapter$2$1.doInBackground(AlbumDetailsAdapter.java:194)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at com.outsoucefarm.musicagratis.functions.AlbumDetailsAdapter$2$1.doInBackground(AlbumDetailsAdapter.java:1)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-29 17:54:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(8701):     ... 5 more
```

So can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
playSong.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_nr);
```

you can't edit your layout from inside a thread,
define a handler at the beginning of your activity's class

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

then use it inside doInBackground:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      playSong.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_nr);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help, I've added the Toast to the handler also, because the toast is also editing the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to manipulate UI elements from the catch block, but you are not on the UI thread as required.

Make your *doInBackground* return **true** if successful, **false** if failed (change *Void* result to *Boolean*) and move all UI-related code to *onPostExecute*.